# Sending Files With Sockets

Tags: c++, winapi, http, sockets, winsock

I'm trying to create a basic HTTP server to learn more about how it works. I'm having difficulties with sending binary files to the client. My code is as below:

```
char * buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 512);
fseek(content_file, 0, SEEK_SET);
while (!feof(content_file)) {
    size_t read = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), content_file);
    if (read > 0) {
        client->send((const void *)buffer);
    }
}
fclose(content_file);
free(buffer);
```

Now I know it can send some unnecessary data after the last block read but before trying to fix it, I want to know what's wrong with it. It was working fine for text files and I was using fgets. But after switching to fread to support binary files, text files are corrupted and became something like this: `ThisÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ` ("This" is the only correct part in the sent data)

Obviously I'm missing something but can you please help me to do this correctly?

### Edit:

Using a `buffer_size` value instead of `sizeof(buffer)` fixed the missing/corrupted data problem.

Comment: Can you show us the signature and/or code for `cleint->send`? Specifically, how does it know how many bytes to send?

Comment: Oh silly me, I was using strlen in client->send :-) Thanks, but I can't mark your comment as solution, so I will go ahead and mark Bo's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You problem is that `sizeof(buffer)` gives you the size of the pointer, not what it points to.

Add a `buffer_size` and use that both for `malloc` and `freed`.

Comment: You can get the file size using this code: fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_END);
 ulFileSize = ftell (fp);
 fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

Comment: Thanks, CariElf. That's what I'm using.